# In iOS, are there any guidelines for how many view controllers an app should have in a navigation stack?

Tags: ios

I am developing an app in which the user can navigate through 6 view controllers and then all the way back if they want to. And now I am concerned about that it is maybe too many view controllers for back navigation. Are there any guidelines about this? I can not find any design guidelines that specifies any limit to how many view controllers is ok for navigating back in an app. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: There is no pre-set limit, AFAIK. Your memory consumption is the technical limitation. IMHO, the more practical issue is the UX, in which nesting six levels can be a little confusing/annoying (e.g. if you want to go back to the second one, you have to tap "back" button four times, which isn't a great UX). Sometimes it's logical, but sometimes it is unwieldy.

Answer (score 0):

This is the link to the iOS Human Interface Guidelines. While there is no hard limit, they do allude to some considerations with you design.

[HIG - Navigation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Navigation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH53-SW1)